# Google CDN jQuery with Local Fallback in Magento Layout XML

Tags: layout, javascript

I've done the following to include jQuery from Google CDN in Magento:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]>
                </text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

However when I want to implement it with a local fallback, which works quite well, I wind up adding it to my .phtml as such:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (!window.jQuery) {
    document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

- Is there a **more elegant** way of doing this **in local.xml** than to shove the fallback into the `<text>` node as I'm doing with `jQuery.noConflict`?

**Edit:**

To draw attention to the other part of the question - are there community modules that include jQuery for you? If they have a local jQuery, that's fine - if they use Google CDN - even better.  If this isn't out there, I would love to create one.

- Are there any go-to extensions that handle this without me having to bootstrap it myself?

Comment: One very simple community module to include JQuery (semi-self-link): https://github.com/netz98/N98_BaseJQuery - it only includes a local JQuery. The idea via CDN is nice, feel free to improve via Pull Requests :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is the CDN unreliable or why is the fallback needed? What kind of practical experience do you have there?

Comment: Some countries (Iran, Syria, et al) may, at times, block Google and Google CDN. This is my personal experience. I've also seen things like response timeouts that this mitigates.

Comment: Understand. So it would be cool if you can contribute a solution to the module.

Comment: Great find - I didn't see the N98 module when looking for something suitable. I think I'll contribute over there. Thanks! However it may have to be with the `<text>` method as described above... not sure if that's an acceptable solution. The n98 module uses a separate js include file for calling noConflict, though, I suppose...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the end of the day, doing this via Layout XML is preferable. I have found that the local fallback option is best implemented in a single-line statement minified with the Google Closure Compiler.

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>window.jQuery||document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery.js">\x3c/script>');</script><script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]></text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: this doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I looked for a long time through the code of the head.phtml files and the files and blocks around but there is no way without changing the templates to inject code into the <head>.</strike>

I'm an idiot, you wrote everything already and I oversaw a few times the `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` in the `head.phtml` :-/

So I would just use a `core/template` block and a template for this. It is easy to read, easy to understand and easy to manage.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to overcome is the ability to add/remove this block from certain page types and layouts at-will without having to forcefully include the phtml every time. Right now a static block suffices, but only because it's available from most everywhere...

Comment: I don't see the problem here. You add it to <default> and remove it, everywhere where you don't want to have it, like every other block. You can think about adding a `core/text_list` and adding there all the stuff you want (if it is more than one file) to easier remove it on other pages.