# Check If JQuery Is Already Included In Head

Tags: magento2, module, layout, javascript, magento-1

I want to check if jQuery is already included on the page. I have seen several methods and finally settled on the following:

```
if ( (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') || !window.jQuery ) {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
```

My question is: is there another/better way to do this? I *sometimes* still have a jQuery conflict because it is fetched twice. Thanks.

Comment: Seams like you are doing it OK. It's simple, it's fast and it works.

Comment: Where is your `noConflict`?

Comment: Below the above code I have `jQuery.noConflict();` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your situation, I think what you have is a good approach.. Though I'm not completely sure why it would sometimes fetch twice and other times not. When I include jQuery, both `jQuery` and `window.jQuery` are defined. However, you can try changing the code to something like this for consistency in your situation:

```
   //use &&
   if ( (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') && !window.jQuery ) {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    } else {
        if((typeof jQuery === 'undefined') && window.jQuery) {
            jQuery = window.jQuery;
        } else if((typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') && !window.jQuery) {
            window.jQuery = jQuery;
        }
    }
```

Note I'm very rusty on how js variables and the `window` object work, and I'm just going off the code logic you have.
Just a side note (and you may already be doing this), put this js in a js file and add it with your module's layout xml

```
<layout version="x.x.x">
    <handle> 
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>pathto/yourmodulesJs/check_jQuery.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </handle>
</layout>
```

Comment: Or, if you want Google CDN jQuery with local fallback: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3523/google-cdn-jquery-with-local-fallback-in-magento-layout-xml

Comment: I may be wrong, but question was how do you check if you don't already have jQuery. I have seen many themes to use it, many modules use it too as well. And most add it in different ways, from different locations. Which causes conflicts. So How do you detect 100% that there is already jQuery loaded so you do not load it again?

Comment: I was adding a sidebar to say that there is more than one way to add jQuery to the page. This may help with detecting.

Comment: @PetarDzhambazov The question didn't mention 3rd party modules or themes. In this case, there is no need to check if it exists because the developer should have full control over that in their layouts. Even in the instance of 3rd party extensions and themes, I think the case is still the same.

Comment: I am, in fact, developing a module. I need to use jQuery functionality and I don't want to break my own or other modules. So, I need to check if jQuery has already been included or not. I don't want to include multiple versions of jQuery (my own and another module's, for example). Then either server the CDN version or not :) Hope that's clear

Comment: *"Normally, this is added to all pages using the default handle in page.xml"* should *not* be the case. This should *normally* be added via custom layout XML file or *local.xml*.

Comment: @Jongosi I think your extension will at best need to grep theme files to see if `jquery` is referenced in any of them, and then provide the user some feedback if it is.

Comment: @benmarks Ah, I thought Magento install has that by default, but it looks like it doesn't, just prototype and some scriptaculous.

Comment: @Jongosi Is this for a local module or a module for community?

Comment: Ultimately for community, but just a local site right now, thx guys

Comment: Thx all, I'll look at @benmarks suggestion

Comment: @Jongosi I updated yet again. Let me know if that helpful at all...

Comment: I'll give it a go, thx Shredder.