# Is there a way to load an external CSS file in local.xml?

Tags: css, external

I found out on [Google CDN jQuery with Local Fallback in Magento Layout XML](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3523/google-cdn-jquery-with-local-fallback-in-magento-layout-xml/3625#3625) from @philwinkle answer that an external js can be loaded to the "head" via local.xml.  Is there also a way to load an external css file via Magento's local.xml so that edits to head.phtml can be avoided?

Comment: It works exactly the same. Replace the script tag with a link tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Philwinkle said, you can modify the code from the post he previously posted.

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="your_external_csv">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://path.com/to/stylesheet.css">]]>
                </text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

It's important to understand what Magento is actually doing here so you understand how to modify it.
A new block is created using the Mage_Core_Block_Text class. This class only has 4 methods: to `get`, `add` and set `text` and a `_toHtml` method that automatically outputs the text when the block is echoed in a phtml file.

In the block you've created just now you're using the `<action>` tag with attribute `method`, `setText` to imply that Magento should create the block and then call the following method or function of this block with, in this case, as argument your external CSS tag. So It doesn't really matter what you give as argument, it will always be outputted in the phtml.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thank you for taking the extra time to explain the logic behind it too that helps!

Comment: No problem, maybe take some time to give the origional post an upvote to ;) http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3523/google-cdn-jquery-with-local-fallback-in-magento-layout-xml/3625#3625

Comment: Keep in mind that the block will be inserted after `addItem` actions, so CSS loaded this way may be blocked by JS files inserted above via `addItem`.

Answer (score 9):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addLinkRel">
            <rel>stylesheet</rel>
            <href>//example.com/css/page.css</href>
        </action>
    </reference>

</default>
</layout>
```

notice i used `//` instead of `http://` or `https://`, this lets the page define which protocol to use automatically

Comment: This works, but does not include a `type="text/css"` attribute.

Comment: as of HTML 4.01 and later, type is not required for the link attribute - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409114/is-type-text-css-necessary-in-a-link-tag

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways. Hook into `<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>` and change the content of

```
\Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::getIncludes
/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php:462
/**
 * Get miscellanious scripts/styles to be included in head before head closing tag
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getIncludes()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['includes'])) {
        $this->_data['includes'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/includes');
    }
    return $this->_data['includes'];
}
```

which is easily possible in the backend.

The alternative is to hook into the `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` check for the block type and just add your html via observer into the transport object.

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:886
```

Comment: Where can I find `public function getIncludes()`?

Comment: added it to the post.